# Convert recursion to dynamic

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

i have a task: array of digits [8 1 2 8 2 10 4 5], need to identify if any elements of its can  be half of it total sum. In example sum of elements is 40, half sum is 20. Elements can  be 8,2,10  or 5,1,4,10 . Don't matter whats digits are, only true or false result.
I check all possible sums of digits by recursion, and I confused how convert it to cycles

```
 private static boolean isExist(int[] data, int n, int sum) {
    if (sum == 0)
        return true;
    if (n <= 0)
        return false;
    if (data[n - 1] == sum)
        return true;
    if (sum < data[n - 1])
        return isExist(data, n - 1, sum);
    return isExist(data, n - 1, sum - data[n - 1]) || isExist(data, n - 1, sum);

}
```

Comment: I think, the problem statement would have mentioned about sum of subsets. Then your statement "Elements can be 8,2,10 or 5,1,4,10" would make sense. If thats the case, you should find all the subsets of that array and then find the sum. BTW sum will never be less than an element.

Comment: No , this is right statement . It's work . I need to rewrite it to cycle instead of recursion. I just described what this code do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make array `A[]` of length `sum+1`, make `A[0]=1`

For every element  of value `e`: check in reverse direction (from the end of array to beginning) `if A[i-e]==1`, in this case make `A[i]=1`.  (This denotes that sum `i` might be composed using current element and previously checked ones)

If `A[sum]` becomes 1, then needed subset does exist.

Working example in Python to demonstrate:

```
L = [7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 7]
S = sum(L) // 2
A = [0]*(S+1)
A[0] = 1
for e in L:
    for i in range(S, e-1, -1):  // scan backward
        if A[i-e]:
            A[i] = 1

print(A, A[-1] > 0)

>>  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]   True

L = [7, 9, 3, 4, 6, 13]
>> [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] False
```

Comment: sorry , but I don't understand. For example, [1 5 7 1 ]  , sum = 7, make array A[8], A[0] = 1, then for 1 element -> A[8] -> 8 - 1 = 7 and 7!=1 , what to save to A[8]-????

Comment: For this case (array size 8) the last element is A[7], and A[7-7]==0, so A[7]=1, and sum exists

Comment: I got bad example,sorry .  For  7 9 3 4 6 7  - sum 18 , we take  7 -> A[18] =  11 , and then wee check A[11]  for  6  element?

Comment: I added Python code

Comment: why we use A[sum+1] ,? what is step beetwen 7 and 6 elements in this array?

Comment: Because the last element of such array is A[sum], and we need A[0] as "empty set is valid"

Comment: `then wee check A[11] for 6 element?` No, we check that sum 11 has been already composed from other elements. This condition doesn't fire for the first 7, but fires for the last 7

Comment: It's very diffecult to undrstand for me. I'll try to figure out. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Try to realize steps. After value 7 the only filled array cell is 7. After 7 and 9 - 7, 9 and 16. After 7, 9,3 - 3,7,9,10,12, 19 and so on